# Rails 3 + Passenger + Apache force WWW and SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mod-rewrite, passenger

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from non-SSL to SSL and force WWW and lastly to redirect an old subdomain to the master domain for a Rails 3 application.

Here is my goal:

```
http://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com

http://api.domain.com -> https://api.domain.com

http://old.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
```

I'm trying to achieve this from apache config file for the domain which looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias api.domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias old.domain.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias api.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/deploy/domain/public
    RailsEnv production
    <Directory /home/deploy/domain/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile /ssldomain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/privateKey.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/domain_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

For some reason the SSL is fine but there is no redirect happening. The rails application works on all 4 options:

```
https://domain.com
https://www.domain.com
https://api.domain.com
https://old.domain.com
```

Any idea how I can clear my apache config file to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose, but all you should need is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  ServerAlias old.domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com
  Redirect / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName api.domain.com
  Redirect / https://api.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then what you have above for the SSL Virtual Host.

Comment: I tried this, reloaded & restarted apache. Same result.

Comment: Silly question, but if you ping each of the above domain names, do they all resolve to the same IP address?

Comment: They all resolve to the same IP. Any way to refresh the permanent redirects in Google Chrome? I tried incognito but is not working. It seems that on my phone the redirect works. Edit: I was wrong, not working on the phone either.

Comment: If the server names and aliases above are correct, and the site is actually running off apache, there's no reason why this shouldn't be working... try removing the :80 virtual hosts altogether and restarting apache - if the site still runs without SSL then there's something else at play (another virtual host perhaps)

Comment: I've deleted all the :80 virtual hosts and none of the domains were working. After I added them back I deleted my browser cache and the :80 redirects were working but the problem is with the :443 it accepts all subdomains and non-www